# How to handle the loss of precision on JDBC numeric types due to grouping functions

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Oracle (and some other DB's) have a datatype NUMBER, with which one can optionally set the precision and scale.

Suppose the below query:

```
SELECT agent_code, 
AVG (opening_amt)
FROM customer 
GROUP BY agent_code;
```

If both fields in above query were defined as NUMBER(12,0), the result in JDBC is indeed that for agent_code, but on "AVG(opening_amt)" both precision and scale return 0 (via java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.getPrecision(col) and java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.getScale(col) .

That's basically the same as NUMBER, without any precision or scale specification, and according to oracle, would equal NUMBER(38,12).

The above loss of precision gives me a problem to determine if the sql type should be converted to Double or Integer.

So, I was wondering if this is actually a bug in Oracle's JDBC driver, or how this should be handled? (and no, using BigDecimal as corresponsting java type is not an option for me).

Comment: Just because the original values may be defined as `NUMBER(12,0)`, doesn't mean their average would have to be of the same type. In fact, that would be a pretty bad thing if you needed to have the average in the best precision possible. You could cast the average to a specific type if you want to control it.

Comment: Agreed. But shouldn't JDBC then return the maximum precision and scale of the field (like Oracle treats it internally), instead of 0,0 ?

Comment: I'd expect so. Is the type of the column (via `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()`) really `Types.NUMERIC`?

Comment: Yes, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC (2)

Comment: Hmm..I looked at how the Postgres driver handles the situation, and it seems to do the exact same thing. For `NUMERIC` columns without specified precision or scale, the internal `atttypmod` value is set to `-1`, resulting in returning `0` from both methods, otherwise the precision and scale are calculated based on `atttypmod`. So not just Oracle to blame here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can cast to any desired type

```
CAST(AVG(opening_amt) AS DECIMAL(12,2))
```

See [the example](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/avg-decimal-places-using-cast-within-avg.php)

> The SQL AVG() function returns the average value with default decimal places. The CAST() is used to increase or decrease the decimal places of a value. The CAST() function is much better at preserving the decimal places when converting decimal and numeric data types. The 'AS DECIMAL' followed by the format specification is used with CAST() for making a numeric value to a specific decimal place value.

Comment: True, but that still leaves the question of why Oracle returns scale and precision as 0, while it's internally using the maximum available values for these two (38,12).

Comment: I think it calculates scale and precision on fly based on results. E.g. if you have NUMBER(1) and sum 10 rows the result could be NUMBER(2) in case of 10k rows... etc. So I guess oracle on fly changes column type based on result of the calculation. It's just my guess no reference to any docs though.

Answer (score 3):

This is speculation based on similar behaviour in the Postgres driver `postgresql-9.4-1204-jdbc42.jar`.

For an unspecified `NUMERIC` the database doesn't seem to store any particular information on the precision and scale of the column. This allows the database to internally store the value in any way it seems fit. From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

> without any precision or scale creates a column in which numeric values of any precision and scale can be stored, up to the implementation limit on precision (up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point)

Since the *driver* doesn't know what the implementation specific maximum of the *server* is, it can't return the actual values. It returns 0 to indicate that it doesn't know the actual values, and doesn't want to make any educated guesses.

Seems like the situation is the [same with Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313). The max precision may be higher, but *portability* is guaranteed only up to 38 digits.

> Numbers of virtually any magnitude can be stored and are guaranteed portable among different systems operating Oracle Database, up to 38 digits of precision.

As for solving the issue in the question, like StanislavL indicated you can force the value to a specific precision/scale by casting.

Comment: Good investigations! Seems our guesses are reasonable. +1